How to build an astro.build app inside a dockerfile (turborepo)
This is my current setup:
FROM node:lts-alpine AS base

FROM base AS builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /repo
RUN npm install -g turbo
COPY . .
COPY ./apps/page/.env.docker ./apps/page/.env

RUN turbo prune --scope=@myturborepo/page --docker

# # Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM base AS installer
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /repo

# # First install the dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY --from=builder /repo/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /repo/out/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml
RUN corepack enable
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

COPY --from=builder /repo/out/full/ .

RUN pnpm dlx turbo run build --filter=@myturborepo/page

FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY --from=installer /repo/apps/page/astro.config.mjs .
COPY --from=installer /repo/apps/page/package.json .
COPY --from=installer /repo/apps/page/node_modules .
COPY --from=installer /repo/apps/page/dist ./dist

# # Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 astrojs

USER astrojs

ARG PORT=4321
ENV PORT=$PORT
ENV HOST="0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "dist/server/entry.mjs"]

Almost every step is copied from the nextjs expample but when i run this it can't find the react package (which is a dependency in the package.json). When i inspect the files in the docker container it seems that it has symlinks in the node_modules pointing to ../../node_modules which now don't exist anymore because of the pruning etc.
I got it to work by just copying the entire app and running it then but that caused the image to be around 700mb. In comparison, nextjs is around 190mb.
Does anyone know what steps i'm missing or what i'm doing wrong?

Astro (unlike Next.js) uses vite under the hood. So perhaps see https://turbo.build/repo/docs/guides/frameworks/vite
